# CloudStack installation: Error creating instance

Tags: centos6, apache-cloudstack

I am a newbie to CloudStack. I installed it using Quick Install Guide on CentOS 6.4 and kvm. As my network is a LAN at my faculty and there is a DHCP and Gateway for connecting to internet, at the beginning I defined address pool of Pod and guest withing the range of LAN addresses. But I wasn't able to create instances getting this error:

2013-06-17 13:44:03,445 DEBUG [cloud.storage.StorageManagerImpl] (Job-Executor-1:job-9) Insufficient un-allocated capacity on: 200 for volume allocation: [Vol[3|vm=3|ROOT]] since its allocated percentage: 2.2468850974329963E7 has crossed the allocated pool.storage.allocated.capacity.disablethreshold: 0.85, skipping this pool

I guessed this is because of IP conflicts between pool and dhcp range. So I re-installed it (removed and re-installed cloud-agent and cloud-client), and this time defined a different subnet for address pools (255.0.0.0) from dhcp subnet (255.255.0.0). But now I'm getting this error while "Creating system VMs" after doing the configuration using UI:

WARN [cloud.consoleproxy.ConsoleProxyManagerImpl] (consoleproxy-1:) Exception while trying to start console proxy com.cloud.exception.AgentUnavailableException: Resource [Host:1] is unreachable: Host 1: Unable to start instance due to Unable to start VM[ConsoleProxy|v-2-VM] due to error in finalizeStart, not retrying at com.cloud.vm.VirtualMachineManagerImpl.advanceStart(VirtualMachineManagerImpl.java:847) at com.cloud.vm.VirtualMachineManagerImpl.start(VirtualMachineManagerImpl.java:472) at com.cloud.vm.VirtualMachineManagerImpl.start(VirtualMachineManagerImpl.java:465) at com.cloud.consoleproxy.ConsoleProxyManagerImpl.startProxy(ConsoleProxyManagerImpl.java:627) at com.cloud.consoleproxy.ConsoleProxyManagerImpl.allocCapacity(ConsoleProxyManagerImpl.java:1164) at com.cloud.consoleproxy.ConsoleProxyManagerImpl.expandPool(ConsoleProxyManagerImpl.java:1981) at com.cloud.consoleproxy.ConsoleProxyManagerImpl.expandPool(ConsoleProxyManagerImpl.java:173) at com.cloud.vm.SystemVmLoadScanner.loadScan(SystemVmLoadScanner.java:113) at com.cloud.vm.SystemVmLoadScanner.access$100(SystemVmLoadScanner.java:34) at com.cloud.vm.SystemVmLoadScanner$1.reallyRun(SystemVmLoadScanner.java:83) at com.cloud.vm.SystemVmLoadScanner$1.run(SystemVmLoadScanner.java:73) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by: com.cloud.utils.exception.ExecutionException: Unable to start VM[ConsoleProxy|v-2-VM] due to error in finalizeStart, not retrying at com.cloud.vm.VirtualMachineManagerImpl.advanceStart(VirtualMachineManagerImpl.java:814) ... 19 more

Is the problem related to IP conflict? If yes, how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a nested hypervisor lab and deploy cloudstack. The easiest way to use cloudstack with opensource Xenserver hypervisor.
Bellow post shows the same process with steps.

Part 2: http://www.cloudometry.in/2015/03/apache-cloudstack-implementation-step_29.html

Part 3: http://www.cloudometry.in/2015/03/apache-cloudstack-implementation-step_96.html

Answer (score 0):

First the last exception:

Some background is required to understand why CloudStack is trying to start a VM on your hypervisor.  The VM is a a System VM.  System VMs are used by CloudOSs to distributed services across a cloud.  Currently, CloudStack has three kinds:  secondary storage, virtual router and console proxy VM.  The console proxy VM allows you to view the virtual framebuffer of a VM.  Usually you need access to the hypervisor itself.  Instead, a console proxy is installed on the hypervisor.  Note that system VMs and user VMs are started using the same code.  Therefore, the exception suggests that there is a general problem with creating VMs.

The specific details of the exception suggest that CloudStack cannot reach the agent on the KVM box.  Why not check that you can SSH from the CloudStack management server to the KVM hypervisor?  Secondly, look at the outgoing connections from the KVM box.  Is there a TCP connection from the agent on the KVM box to the CloudStack management server?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I installed all on a single machine. So management server and cloud agent are on the same system. I can't ping or ssh to system VMs. I'd rather install it again as I couldn't find out what the problem is. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Single machine?  Try [DevCloud](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CLOUDSTACK/DevCloud)